# Expand colliding UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, overlapping, cgpoint

I'm facing a hard algorithm...

I'm developing an iOS app where I have a radius map, where in the middle there's my profile image and arround the profile image there are other profiles images from other users.
The thing is that some of these profiles are overlapping and I would like to expand them.

My goal is to get the closest profile from me and check for if there's some other profile overlapping it. If it is, take that profile and move it away from the other profile.

[The profiles overlaping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq7BG.png)

[The profile moved from the nearest profile to the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2O16.png)

Can someone please help me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved with this code:

```
    int tries = 0;
    while(true){
        BOOL f = NO;
        for(Dot *dot1 in dots){

            for(Dot *dot2 in dots){

                if(dot1 == dot2)
                    continue;

                CGFloat distance = fabs([self distanceFromView:dot1 toView:dot2]);

                if(distance < 36.0){

                    f = YES;

                    CGFloat bearing = atan2((dot2.suggestedCenter.y - dot1.suggestedCenter.y) , (dot2.suggestedCenter.x - dot1.suggestedCenter.x));

                    CGPoint vector = CGPointMake( 36.0 * cosf( bearing ), 36.0 * sinf( bearing ));

                    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake( dot1.suggestedCenter.x + vector.x, dot1.suggestedCenter.y + vector.y );
                    dot2.suggestedCenter = newPoint;

                }

            }

        }
        if(!f)
            break;
        tries ++;
        if(tries > 100)
            break;
    }
```

Where 36.0 is the width of the dot and distanceFromView:toView: is:

```
    -(double)distanceFromView:(Dot *)from toView:(Dot *)to{
        return sqrt(pow(to.suggestedCenter.x - from.suggestedCenter.x, 2) + pow(to.suggestedCenter.y - from.suggestedCenter.y, 2));
    }
```

Hope that helps someone.